# iOS 8 - change orientation back to portrait when dismissing full screen AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, fullscreen, avplayer

my app is a portrait only app, but I have one view controller which is displaying a live stream, using an AVPlayerViewController.

To allow landscape for the full screen view of that player I wrote this method in the **AppDelegate.swift**:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> Int {
    var orientation =  UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait

    if let presentedController = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController? {

        if presentedController.isKindOfClass( NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController").self ) {
            orientation = .AllButUpsideDown
        } else if let navController = presentedController as? UINavigationController {
            if navController.topViewController.isKindOfClass( NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController").self ) {
               orientation = .AllButUpsideDown
            }
        }
    }

    return  Int(orientation.rawValue)
}
```

This is how I call initialise my AVPlayer:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showLiveStream" {

        SVProgressHUD.show()
        var queue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)

        dispatch_async(queue, {
            let streamURL = NSURL(string: liveStreamURL)
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: streamURL)
            let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                var playerViewController = segue.destinationViewController as AVPlayerViewController
                playerViewController.player = player
            })
        })
    }
}
```

The problem: when I open up the full screen view of the player, then change to landscape and then click "Done" to dismiss the full screen view, my app stays in landscape. But I want it to rotate to portrait again. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you subclassing `AVPlayerViewController` with your `AVFullScreenViewController` class?

Comment: @LaurentRivard No, the `AVFullScreenViewController` class is the AVKit equivalent to the `MPInlineVideoFullscreenViewController` runtime class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than implementing `application(_:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:)` try implementing `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` on *each* view controller. So for example:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}
```

This will ensure that the view controller cannot be displayed in landscape, so when dismissing the video player, it will come straight back to a portrait window.

**Update** Objective-C:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations { 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; 
}
```

Comment: Can you please add objective c for this answer?

Answer (score 1):

What i did to fix this issue, create a new class with a 'viewDidLayoutSubviews' function and override it!

```
final class NewMoviePlayerViewController: AVPlayerViewController {
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if view.bounds == contentOverlayView?.bounds {
            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
            UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add These Lines in Appdelegate and your Required View Controller**

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO; 
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //LandScapeMode:- UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    //PortraitMode:- 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait 
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    //LandScapeMode:- UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
   // ProtraitMode:-
   return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
}
```